# How can I pass PrintLastLog option to one ssh run only (without changing the ssh_config)

Tags: ssh

I would like to disable the `PrintLastLog` option for only one run of the `ssh` command.

I tried to pass it using the `-o` option:

```
 ssh -q -o PrintLastLog=no localhost
```

but I get:

```
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: printlastlog
```

I also don't see the `PrintLastLog` option in the `SSH_CONFIG(5)` `man` file. Are there options that are special and cannot be passed as command line flags?

The reason for the question is that I need to ssh to several servers from a script, and I don't want the MOTD/login message clogging up the log output from the script.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see it there, because it's an option for the sshd **daemon**, not the client. You can't change server options from the client side.

However, if what you want is to do ssh in a script without doing output, you can simply redirect the output to /dev/null. Example:

```
for i in `< /file/with/hostnames`; do ssh $i hostname > /dev/null; done
```

When you use SSH to just issue a command, the only output you will get is from that command - you won't get the MOTD or the banner. And since you're redirecting that output to /dev/null, you're getting nothing.

Comment: Indeed! Good point! :)

Comment: is there a way to tell the daemon from the client that the welcome message is not wanted?

Comment: I think you're having an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/214153). What is your reason for wanting to suppress this message?

Comment: I have a script that adds several hosts to the `known_hosts` before it will start to run in order to avoid the interactive mode asking the user permission to add a certain server fingerprint key. This script causes a lot of "garbage" in the terminal because of the servers that print welcome messages/last log.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay Definitely an XY problem, and now you have the answer! (And I edited your post to clarify this, hope you're OK with the edit.)